# Java: submenu in jpopupmenu with separators and shortcut keys that appear?

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu

how do you go about adding submenu's to an existing jpopupmenu?

when you right click the jpopupmenu appears, I want to access submenus under another menu.

how do you add separators in the jpopupmenu? what about shortcut keys?

Below image describes what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For separators, you will need [JSeparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSeparator.html), see example [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/AddSeparatortoMenu.htm).

For binding a shortcut, you will need to call [setMnemonic](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMnemonic%28char%29), see example [here](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/HCI/HCI_Handout_CALLER/node79.html).

For sub-menu, simply add a [JMenu](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html) to an existing JMenu/JPopupMenu as a child, see example [here](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/HCI/HCI_Handout_CALLER/node79.html).

Note: links 4-6 are the same one

Comment: JMenu has an addSeparator() method, which ultimately uses a custom Separator class.

Answer (score 2):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for working examples and explanations.